# restore default firewall config for esxi 5.5

Tags: vmware-esxi

While trying to add a new firewall rule file I accidentally copied my new XML over the top of the primary /etc/vmware/firewall/service.xml config file. I'm booting our free ESXI 5.5 server from a USB flash drive. I'm not sure whether the modified service.xml file will persist through a reboot but if it does the firewall settings will be missing all the default entries. Is there a way to retrieve that file from a config backup, the USB flash drive or perhaps an online repository? I've looked at our state.tgz backup files and they do not appear to contain the service.xml file.

Comment: Copy the file from a known-good esxi host?

Comment: I only have the one 5.5 server. I've copied the file from a 5.1 server however I can see from the current ruleset that the two files are not identical. ESXi 5.5 appears to have added additional rules. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: So stand up another 5.5 server?  It's like 10 minutes work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installed ESXi 5.5 in a VirtualBox VM and extracting the file that way.